# How do I make the width and height of a child element the minimum of it's parent's width and height

Tags: css, sass

How do I make the width and height of a child element the minimum of it's parent's width and height. Just so it can become a square that is contained in its dynamic parent. Something like:

```
.child{
    height: min(parent-height, parent-width);
    width: min(parent-height, parent-width);
 }
```

I even tried using css variables like

```css
.parent{
   --parent-width: width; /* I also used min-content and max-content */
   --parent-height: height; /* also used min-content and max-content */
}

.parent .child{
   width: var(--parent-width);
   height: var(--parent-height);
}
```

```html
<!-- The parent of .parent is dynamic -->
<div class="parent" style="width:100%; height:100%;">
   <div class="child" style="background:red"></div>
</div>
```

It didn't word either

Comment: So are you trying to make the child maintain a certain aspect ratio?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.parent
{
  background-color:green;
  width:300px;
}
.child
{
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">Hello, I am Child</div>
 </div>
```

If you set the parent's width and height, the 100% child width and height will be adjusted as per parents width and height.

Comment: I want the child to be a square. It is an empty div

Answer (score 0):

Plz add this css style..

**CSS**

```
.parent{
  display:flex;
  display:-webkit-flex;
  align-items:center;
  -webkit-align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: It still doesn't solve it. I just modified the question. I guess I wasn't very explanatory before. You could help me check it please